# How to transfer entire iTunes library from one iPhone to another?

Tags: ios, itunes, mac, restore

I got a new iPhone, and restored it from a backup of my old iPhone. Then I noticed that the iTunes library was empty excluding the stock U2 tracks.

If I move the entire "iTunes_Control" folder from the old iPhone to the new one, the music library seems to be there on the new phone, but none of the songs are playable "in my region". None of it is Apple Music, from iCloud or whatever online service, all are `mp3` and `m4a`s from my computer.

I want to restore everything from the old iTunes library to the new phone, including playlists, statistics, album art as a backup should.

Comment: What are the two phones' iOS versions? Are the two phones connected to the same "regions" or to different ones? Are the two phones both logged in to the same iCloud account?

Comment: @David old device has iOS 12.0, new one has latest iOS 13, both are connected to the same region and the same iCloud account.